# Create separate files based on 2 variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite my macro (that I use already to create files containing records based on a date) so that it continues to create separate files but based on an additional variable, e.g. on date and type.
Some additional input:

- the date is selected by the user through a userForm containing 'Selected Date'; this value is passed on to the macro;
- the type (as is the date), is part of the data record

Here's are the columns in the entire record:

| Date | Type | Product | Currency | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210401 | 1 | A | EUR | 1548 |
| 20210401 | 2 | A | EUR | 1579 |
| 20210401 | 1 | A | EUR | 1589 |

Using the table above, I would like to create separate files called `FILE_20210401_1.txt` and `FILE_20210401_2.txt` file creation is controlled by a) the date, and b) the type. This means my first file would contain 2 records, the latter only 1.

All goes fine with regard to file names and storing the files.

The content, however, is the bottleneck, as the macro now includes all records in both files. I have tried many things using a loop and a double loop, but I guess I'm missing something to tell the macro i want to have a file grouped per date and type. This is what I have so far in the macro:

```
Sub
    Dim sRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim SelectedDate As String
    Dim TDate As String
    Dim Type As Variant

    SelectedDate = Range("AA2").Value  'Selected Date entered on the userForm
    Set sRange = Range("A2:E4").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
       
    If TDate = SelectedDate Then
        For i = 2 To sRange.Rows.Count
            'set date column
            TDate = sRange.Range("A" & i) 'TDate is in column A of the range
            For m = 2 To sRange.Rows.Count
                Type = sRange.Range("B" & m) 'Type is in column B of the range
     'define directories and file location
     If Len(Dir(MyFolder1, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
      If Len(Dir(MyFolder2, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
       If Len(Dir(MyFolder3, vbDirectory)) <> 0 Then
          filename = MyFolderFull & "\FILE_" & SelectedDate & "_" & Type & ".txt"
       Else: MkDir MyFolder3
           filename = MyFolderFull & "\FILE_" & SelectedDate & "_" & Type & ".txt"
       End If
      Else: MkDir MyFolder2
            MkDir MyFolder3
            filename = MyFolderFull & "\FILE_" & SelectedDate & "_" & Type & ".txt"
      End If
     Else: MkDir MyFolder1
           MkDir MyFolder2
           MkDir MyFolder3
           filename = MyFolderFull & "\FILE_" & SelectedDate & "_" & Type & ".txt"
     End If

                Open filename For Output As #1
                Print #1
                Close #1
            Next m
        Next i
    End if

    MsgBox "Files created!"
End Sub
```

Any ideas as to what I am forgetting here?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do `Date = Range.Range("A" & i)` Note that `Date` is a reserved word. If you used it as a variable name you need to change that variable name. Don't use reserved words to name variables. • Please provide a [mcve] of your issue, or at least the relevant code part including the variable declarations.

Comment: Please note that the code does not reflect how this will produce 2 different files. We are not able to reproduce your issue with only the code you showed. Relevant parts are missing.

Comment: @PEH - i updated the question with what I have in the macro so far. If it still does not tell you that it must produce 2 files then obviously I'm missing that part... And in fact, the above code actually produces two files! The problem is that each file contains all records which means it is not using the variables and just loops through all records.

Comment: The variable `SelectedDate` is empty in your code as well as `TDate` is empty when you run `If TDate = SelectedDate Then`. Please clarify if this is your real code or just a copy paste mistake? • Another approach proposal. Sort your data for Date AND Type, then loop through it row wise when the type or date changes write the file otherwise collect the data. • Are you able to sort the data or is it not possible?

Comment: TDate should match any Date found in Range; SelectedDate comes from the userForm. This could be a mistake as I played around a little bit with the location of the IF.  When i put it below 'TDate = Range.Range("A" & i)' then TDate is known. Sorting is applied.

Comment: but in `If TDate = SelectedDate Then` both variables are empty so the `If` statemant is always `True` that does not make any sense. I don't get what you tried.

Comment: the objective of the comparison is to filter all records in Range based on Selected Date, which is entered in a userForm.

Comment: But how can VBA or we know what `SelectedDate` is if you don't tell VBA. This `Dim SelectedDate As String` creates the variable (empty) and when your code comes here `If TDate = SelectedDate Then` this variable is still empty because you never set a value to it. Where is the selected date in your sheet? Also `Dim Range As Range` cannot work because `Range` is a reserved word so you cannot name a variable `Range`. Names must be unique or you get a lot of confusion going on. Imagine you name all your kids the same name, that won't be working out well.

Comment: right, understood. I thought it was sufficient to tell that the SelectedDate is coming from the userForm. I explicitly set the date to the cell containing the value (which is on a different sheet, so not part of sRange).

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains:

```
Open filename For Output As #1
```

It should be:

```
filename = "FILE_" & CStr(TDATE) & "_" & CStr(i)
Open filename For Output As #1
```

(Something like that, I didn't test it)